# Debugging Python code run by embedded Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python

I'm writing a python plugin for an application. In the first phase I wrote a mockup in python to test/debug this plugin. I set up vscode to launch the plugin code as normal python app.

Now I want to go to the next step and run the plugin code in a C++ application with embedded Python and want to be able to debug the python code loaded by this embedded interpreter. I defined a task to launch that binary, which runs endlessly until it is stopped by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

The question is now how to correctly configure the debug launch config in vscode to be able to debug my plugin which runs in the C++ app (it's picked up automatically by that app, from my python project).

This is my task for the external binary:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "mysqlsh",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "mysqlsh",
            "args": [
                "--py",
                "-e",
                "'gui.core.start_web_server(port=8000)'"
            ],
            "isBackground": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

and that's the launch config:

```json
        {
            "name": "Shell",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "mysqlsh",
            "program": "$(file)",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        },
```

While this runs the external app it doesn't stop on any breakpoint in my code. That webserver however is from my code so I know it's running the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, debugging embedded python is exactly like debugging with standalone python. All you have to do is to launch your app you want to debug (manually or with a task).

The create a new debug config for Python (Attach using Process ID). That will create the new launch config. Now run this and you should find your app in the list of the running apps vscode shows you. Pick the right one and after a few seconds the debug session becomes active.

You might also see a source file selector. You can ignore (cancel) that if the code is in the project for which you created the launch config.

It's interesting that the debugger interface in Python is always active, even for the embedded tool, but makes debugging certainly a lot easier, as when you had to enable something first.

Note: you cannot use a pre-launch task to run your binary, because that's run too late (after the process picker was shown), so you have to use a differnt way to launch it.